# Что такое "совдеп"?

Tags: этимология

Когда хотят презрительно сказать о временах застоя, то употребляют слово "совок" или "совдеп". Как я понимаю, "совдеп" — это какое-то сокращение, а вот какое?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Совет (народных) депутатов. Страна же носила неофициальное название "совдепия", которое не было на момент появления чем-то однозначно уничижительным, пробольшевицки настроенными массами произносилось скорее с гордостью. Чуть позже "совдепия" трансформировалось в "совдеп", а уже, видимо, оно относительно недавно (в 60-х?) и превратилось в "совок" - уже с явно негативным оттенком.

Хотя нет, вру. По мелочи, правда. 
В момент появления этого мема (т.е. сразу после революции 1917 года - сами советы ведут историю с 1905 г.) они носили названия типа "Совет Рабочих, Крестьянских, Солдатских и Батрацких депутатов". 
Название несколько варьируется, первый раз после революции закреплено в Конституции 1918 г. в виде "Советов рабочих, крестьянских, красноармейских и казачьих депутатов", но "совдепия" появилась без сомнения еще до этого официального закрепления названия.

Answer (score 1):

**Сов**ет **деп**утатов. Это орган местного самоуправления РСФСР времён Гражданской войны. Совдепией - в белогвардейской прессе презрительно называли всю РСФСР в целом. "Совдеп" в значении "совок" видимо пришло с той эпохи.